# Error when trying to display a raster from command line! (GRASS GIS)

Tags: raster, grass-gis, display, command-line, shell

I am using GRASS GIS 7.8 on Ubuntu 20.04. Currently working my way through a couple of tutorials. I am trying to display a raster from the command line using the `d.rast` command on a new monitor that I've opened up before (d.mon=wx0). In the shell there is no Error, however a new window pops up containing the following error:

```
Rendering failed: Expecting 720x480 image but got 720x456 image.
```

I am using the spearfish dataset from the GRASS GIS website and the raster I want to display is the spot.image. Any clew what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long-standing yet spurious bug which I reported a few days ago: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/1062

A solution is in preparation (https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/1062). I expect that it will be available in GRASS GIS 7.8.5.

In case you do not want to wait: since only Python code is affected you may modify your local installation, following the changes proposed here: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/1064/files